# sensors показывает два значения температуры для каждого ядра

Tags: linux

Команда sensors из пакета lm-sensors показывает две температуры для каждого ядра. Как с этим бороться?

```
kraamis@kr-deb [~]$ sensors
k8temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Core0 Temp:   +41.0°C  
Core0 Temp:   +40.0°C  
Core1 Temp:   +43.0°C  
Core1 Temp:   +40.0°C  

nouveau-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:     +1.05 V  (min =  +0.95 V, max =  +1.10 V)
temp1:        +59.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +100.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
```

Comment: странно это... не работал с amd, может это так и задумано — два датчика прилеплены на каждое ядро? в любом случае lm_sensors не виноват — он только берёт информацию у ядра... Можно проверить, что она соответствует примерно так: `grep -r . $(readlink -f /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon*) | sort`; если это действительно критично, то копать нужно в сторону настройки модуля `k8temp`...

Comment: Да оно не особо критично, просто любопытно стало.